# About when it is called a handler in Boost.Asio

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm learning Boost.Asio. In the documentation we can see the following:

> Asynchronous completion handlers will only be called from threads that
>   are currently calling io_service::run().

I have only a thread (the main thread). In that thread, I call the `io_service::run()` function.

Suppose that the thread is busy when Asio call handler.

Is the handler called? Wait for the thread? Is it ignored?

Thank you

Comment: If `io_service::run` is executed in one thread, all the handlers get called sequentially - one by one. So, if one handler takes too much time to complete, the others are waiting in the queue.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was wrong and I can not delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm wrong.

The handler always will be called since you call one of these functions: run(), run_one(), poll() or poll_one()

My code was wrong. I used the run_one() function with a timer. The timer was failure.